# String literals vs const char* in C

Tags: c

Why don't ANSI C compilers flag the use of a string literal argument in a function call in which the correponding parameter does not have a const qualifier?   For example, the following code could generate an exception by trying to write to read only memory.

```
void somefunc(char buffer[10]);

void somefunc(char buffer[10]) {
    int i;

    for (i = 0;   i < 10;   i++)
       buffer[i] = 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    somefunc("Literal");
    return 0;
}
```

This situation could be identified at compile time but VS2010 and gcc don't appear to do so.  Calling somefunc with a const char* argument will generate a compiler warning.

Comment: Good question - gcc doesn't catch this either, even with `-Wextra`.

Comment: What's the point of declaring a function, then defining it the next line? :)

Comment: Hans:  I've modified the question to specify ANSI C.  Anyway, I wasn't suggesting a compiler error be issued.  A level 3 or 4 warning would simply highlight a potentially dangerous situation.

Comment: Just a side-note: The arguments of `main` are inverted, the correct signature is `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`.

Comment: Just to clarify - my question is not "why are string literals not treated as const char*?" but "why don't we get a compiler warning when calling somefunc() with a string literal argument?"  As lunaryorn points out the function signature provides the compiler with enough info to issue this warning.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

gcc: Use the flag `-Wwrite-strings`

PS. gcc manual explains why this isn't part of -Wall. Anyway, as always, you should find a combination of -W flags that suits your particular needs and coding style. For example, in a recent project I have used something like this: `-Werror -Wall -Wextra -Wformat=2 -Winit-self -Wswitch-enum -Wstrict-aliasing=2 -Wundef -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wbad-function-cast -Wcast-qual -Wcast-align -Wwrite-strings -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wredundant-decls -Wnested-externs -Winline -Wdisabled-optimization -Wunused-macros -Wno-unused`

Answer (score 16):

It is a K&R legacy.  Fixing it would break a million programs.

Answer (score 7):

What Hans Passant said. const was added as part of the ANSI standard on 1989, so anything from before that didn't have const.

Comment: @Georg: I mean the const keyword was added in ANSI C, so it was already too late to retrofit string literals with constness.

Answer (score 6):

string literals are not const in C; in C++ they are.

edit: to clear up any confusion about my comment, I am referring to the type, not the ability to actually change them.

Comment: @Paul, he's correct.  C99 §6.4.5/5: "For character string literals, the array elements have type `char`"  It is undefined to modify a string literal, but the element type is `char`, not `const char`.

Comment: @Matthew: thanks for the clarification - I was interpreting "const" to mean "read-only" (which of course string literals usually are in C or C++) but I see what you mean about the actual *type* of the string literal now.

Answer (score 4):

The GNU compiler (and the Intel C compiler as well, iirc) will emit a warning, if `-Wwrite-string` is used:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wwrite-strings -o foo /tmp/foo.c
/tmp/foo.c: In function 'main':
/tmp/foo.c:12: warning: passing argument 1 of 'somefunc' discards qualifiers from pointer target type
/tmp/foo.c:3: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
```

Concerning VS2010, I can't help you.

Comment: Cool - I wonder why `-Wwrite-strings` isn't included in `-Wall` or even `-Wextra` though ?