# Is text in code char or const char?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [String literals vs const char* in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303411/string-literals-vs-const-char-in-c)

Why i can do this?

```
void foo(char * cstr) {
    ...
}
```

and in code

```
foo("some text");
```

shouldnt "some text" be of type **const** char * ?

if its char *, means i can modify it?

Comment: Try compiling it with all warnings turned on.

Comment: I believe answer is different for the two languages you tagged the question with

Comment: @Peter: Then why did you tag the question `c`?

Comment: i wanted to see also the C point of view... moreover, i came across this issue on a C library, which iam using in C++

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it should be `const`.

In C++03, you are allowed to omit the `const` only for backward compatibility with C, but with two caveats:

- You are *still* not allowed to modify the data. Yes, this is highly confusing. That's why leaving out `const` is *deprecated*. Ideally it would be plain disallowed (and, in C++11 onwards, it is).
- If you have your compiler's warning level set properly, you will be warned when trying to do this. If you have your compiler's error level set really strictly then it will be treated as an *error*.

Comment: Your answer only applies to C++, please mark it as such (Pmg has an answer for C). Nevertheless, +1 from me (for both).

Comment: Note also, that in C++0x the implicit conversion from `const char*` to `char*` that was there for C compatibility has been dropped, and so it will become an error to point a non-const `char*` to a string literal (which by the way is of type `const char[N]` --array of N constant characters, where N includes the NUL termination)

Comment: @David: I think I said that already! And note that it was never really a `char const*` to `char*` conversion that was allowed, but string literal to `char*` conversion. [There is a not-so-subtle difference.](http://codepad.org/PbBi7TfN)

Answer (score 10):

**In C, string literals are of type `char[N]`**, where N is just large enough for all characters in the string literal plus the terminating null byte.

the string literal `"foobar"`, in C, has type `char [7]`. Its use often decays to a pointer to its first element, of type `char*`.

*I believe, treatment of string literals in C++ is different.*

Answer (score 4):

It is a `const char *`. Running the following on ideone (gcc-4.5.1)

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(char * cstr) {
  std::cout << cstr << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  foo( "Hello, World!" );

  return 0;
}
```

produces the desired output along with these warnings

```
prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
prog.cpp:9:24: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'
```

Comment: -1: You get a *warning*, not an *error*, so the call to `foo(char*)` is allowed. So you proved that `"Hello, World!"` is not plain `const char*`, as the latter is not implicitly convertable to `char*`. How can you conclude that you proved the exact opposite?

Comment: Huh? I proved that a deprecated conversion exists from a string literal to a `char *`. I didn't think I needed to prove that string literals decay to `const char *` quite readily.

Comment: iam using C++ GCC 4.2, in XCode, with default settings, which dont show any warning

Comment: @Peter Lapisu: Try compiling with `-Wall` and / or `-pedantic`

Comment: @Praetorian Indeed, you proved that a conversion exists from string literal to `char *`, which does not exist for `const char*`. But you claimed that `"Hello, World!"` has type `const char*`! Non-sequitor.

Comment: @Sjoerd: OK, I see what you mean. I should've been more clear and said the literal has type `const char[N]` which decays to a `const char *` that points to the first character in the literal.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it should be `const char*` , but this code compiles due to backward compatibility reasons. But you can not modify the `str`; if you try to do so it will be undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Along with other answers:

In C++, there exists an implicit conversion from a string literal to `char*`.

```
char* p = "Hello"; //Legal, but dangerous
```

This conversion is dangerous and exists for reasons of compatibility with C. It is explicitly deprecated in C++03 standard. ***In C++0x the conversion was removed!***

```
char* p = "Hello"; //compiler error in C++0x
```

my2c

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically speaking, it should be `const char*`, and then the compiler won't complain anything.

However, to your question, in fact you **might** modify it under some conditions (it depends on the operating system). The compiler just checks whether your code meets the requirements of C programming, and after the code being compiled and linked into an executable file, it will be the business of the OS.

That's to say, you have chance to make achievement to modify a 'const' data. Take linux and gcc for example:

The string "some text" will be put in the `.rodata` segment (so if we don't play some tricks, it would be a segment fault when modifying the string). And there are some tricks we can try:

1. Use `mprotect` to modify the write authority status to the .rodata segment.
2. Or, when linking the objects, link the .rodata segment to .data segment, by using gcc linker script like:

   ```
   .data : {
       *(.rodata) 
       *(.data .data.* .gnu.linkonce.d.*)
   }
   ```

   Name it as **ldscript.lds** then run gcc:

   ```
   gcc test.c -Wl,-T,ldscript.lds -o test.out
   ```

   That will make the "some text" writable, because it's in the .data segment.

Maybe there are other tricks that can achieve this funny play, I cannot list all of them here. Whatever, it's just for fun, you will never be suggested to do that :-p

**EDIT**
Well, someone told me that my linker script method did not work. Unfortunately my computer is currently without Linux. So, I try this in Windows+MinGW and succeed.

1. Use `ld -verbose` to get the default linker script. Then, copy the contents in `.rdata` section (in Linux that's `.rodata`) to `.data` section assignment. In my environment, that is:

   ```
     .data BLOCK(__section_alignment__) :
     {
       __data_start__ = . ;
       *(.data)
       *(.data2)
       *(SORT(.data$*))
       *(.jcr)
       __data_end__ = . ;
       *(.data_cygwin_nocopy)
       *(.rdata)
       *(SORT(.rdata$*))
       *(.eh_frame)
       ___RUNTIME_PSEUDO_RELOC_LIST__ = .;
       __RUNTIME_PSEUDO_RELOC_LIST__ = .;
       *(.rdata_runtime_pseudo_reloc)
       ___RUNTIME_PSEUDO_RELOC_LIST_END__ = .;
       __RUNTIME_PSEUDO_RELOC_LIST_END__ = .;
     }
   ```

   Then delete `.rdata : {...}`, save the file as a linker script file **script.lds**.
2. Here's my **test.c**:

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>

   void foo(char* p){
       *p = 'f';
   }

   int main(){
       const char *str = "sunny";

       puts(str);
       foo(str);
       puts(str);

       return 0;
   }
   ```
3. When I make it through

   ```
   gcc test.c
   ```

   And run a.exe, it crashes, of course.
4. And This try:

   ```
   gcc test.c -Wl,-T,script.lds
   ```

   Running a.exe, finally, it outputs normally:

   ```
   sunny
   funny
   ```

-,- That's all I can explain.