# How to distinguish a malloced string from a string literal?

Tags: c, string, char, malloc

Is there a way (in pure C) to distinguish a `malloc`ed string from a string literal, without knowing which is which? Strictly speaking, I'm trying to find a way to check a variable whether it's a malloced string or not and if it is, I'm gonna free it; if not, I'll let it go.

Of course, I can dig the code backwards and make sure if the variable is `malloc`ed or not, but just in case if an easy way exists...

edit: lines added to make the question more specific.

```
char *s1 = "1234567890"; // string literal
char *s2 = strdup("1234567890"); // malloced string
char *s3;
...
if (someVar > someVal) {
    s3 = s1;
} else {
    s3 = s2;
}
// ...
// after many, many lines of code an algorithmic branches...
// now I lost track of s3: is it assigned to s1 or s2?
// if it was assigned to s2, it needs to be freed;
// if not, freeing a string literal will pop an error
```

Comment: Not in any portable way, no.  Why would you need to anyway?  Sounds like you're attempting to manage memory the wrong way. There are better ways to guarantee that memory is allocated and cleaned up properly.  The first step is to not "forget" how something was allocated.

Comment: I'm not a C/C++ programmer, but this seems kinda obvious so probably I'm missing something. Anyway, if you need to free `s2`, do you care at all about `s3` if it is going to be assigned the value of `s1` or `s2`, and nothing else? You're not going to free the string returned by `strdup` twice, so if you're going to free `s2` anyway, why do you care about `s3`?

Comment: When you write code in C you do so while making strong guarantees about "who" owns memory.  Does the caller own it?  Then it's their responsibility to deallocate it.  Does the callee own it?  Similar thing.  You write code which is very clear about the chain of custody and ownership and you don't run into problems like "who deallocates this?"  And, as Lasse said, if you call `free` on `s2` *and* `s3` you end up with undefined behavior.

Comment: @Ed S.: Well said! You should really make this an answer.

Comment: Note: even though `char *s1 = "1234567890"` is legal code, it is better written as `const char *s1 = "1234567890"`.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303411/string-literals-vs-const-char-in-c

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there a way (in pure C) to distinguish a malloced string from a string literal,

Not in any portable way, no.  No need to worry though; there are better alternatives.

When you write code in C you do so while making strong guarantees about "who" owns memory. Does the caller own it? Then it's their responsibility to deallocate it. Does the callee own it? Similar thing.

You write code which is very clear about the chain of custody and ownership and you don't run into problems like "who deallocates this?" You shouldn't feel the need to say:

```
// after many, many lines of code an algorithmic branches...
// now I forgot about s3: was it assigned to s1 or s2?
```

The solution is; don't forget!  You're in control of your code, just look up the page a bit.  Design it to be bulletproof against leaking memory out to other functions without a clear understanding that "hey, you can read this thing, but there are no guarantees that it will be valid after X or Y.  It's not your memory, treat it as such."

Or maybe it is your memory.  Case in point; your call to `strdup`.  `strdup` let's you know (via documentation) that it is your responsibility to deallocate the string that it returns to you.  How you do that is up to you, but your best bet is to limit its scope to be as narrow as possible and to only keep it around for as short a time as necessary.

It takes time and practice for this to become second nature.  You will create some projects which handle memory *poorly* before you get good at it.  That's ok; your mistakes in the beginning will teach you exactly what *not* to do, and you'll avoid repeating them in the future (hopefully!)

Also, as @Lasse alluded to in the comments, you don't have to worry about `s3`, which is a copy *of a pointer*, not the entire chunk of memory.  If you call free on `s2` and `s3` you end up with undefined behavior.

Comment: Addition to the case: Let's say `s1` is a literal & `s2` is a var (as the code says). The code branches with an `if` and assigns the value of either `s1` or `s2` to `s3`, depending on some condition. Then a function foo(s3) is called. Now, if I need to free `s3` in func. `foo`, I -no longer- have any clue about `s3`. In order to make sure, I have pass the other two vars (`someVar` & `someVal`) to the func. `foo` and **re-evaluate** the condition. Only by passing the other variables, I can be sure about the pointer value of `s3`, whether it was assigned to `s1` or `s2`.

Comment: @merkez3110: Your problem is not the one that you describe. The real issue is that you have already violated the rules I am talking about.  When you designed your code in such a way that this could happen you have already lost.  You create a system which is difficult to maintain and to reason about.  The solution; don't do that.  *"Now, if I need to free s3 in func. `foo`..."* - No, you don't!  You have clouded who is responsible for that memory. if `foo` can accept any string *then it should not be responsible for deallocation*.

Comment: ...The caller of `foo` is responsible because only it knows the correct thing to do.  You have incorrectly pushed responsibility/ownership to a function which cannot reason about its input. *That* is the problem.  It is a design issue, not a technical one.  Look at standard library functions; how many function do you see which take a `char*` and *also* deallocate it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a practical way:

Although the C-language standard **does not** dictate this, for all identical occurrences of a given literal string in your code, the compiler generates a single copy within the RO-data section of the executable image.

In other words, every occurrence of the string `"1234567890"` in your code is translated into the same memory address.

So at the point where you want to deallocate that string, you can simply compare **its address** with the address of the literal string `"1234567890"`:

```
if (s3 != "1234567890") // address comparison
    free(s3);
```

To emphasize this again, it is not imposed by the C-language standard, but it is practically implemented by any decent compiler of the language.

---

**UPDATE:**

The above is merely a practical trick referring directly to the question at hand (rather than to the motivation behind this question).

Strictly speaking, if you've reached a point in your implementation where you have to distinguish between a statically allocated string and a dynamically allocated string, then I would tend to guess that your initial design is flawed somewhere along the line.

Comment: Another possible "practical technique" is to figure out the part of the address space that your system uses for heap, and see if the string is in that.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: I thought about this too, but couldn't think of how to express it in code. The only option guaranteed to work is looking in your linker settings (or configuration file).