# How to free a pointer in struct?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

This is my code:

```
typedef struct bobTheBuilder{
    char *name;
    int fix;
    int max;
};

int main(void){

    struct bobTheBuilder bob;
    initBob(&bob);
    del(&bob);

    system("PAUSE");
    return (0);
}

void initBob(struct bobTheBuilder *currBob)
{
    char *n="bob";
    currBob->name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(n));
    strcpy((*currBob).name, n);
    (*currBob).fix = 0;
    (*currBob).max = 3;
}

void del(struct bobTheBuilder *currBob)
{
    free(currBob->name);
}
```

Visual studio breaks at the `free` sentence.

What should i do?
Is the problem with the `free` or the `malloc`?

Comment: Providing functionality to deallocate a string in the "destructor" of your data structure is a bad idea: what if someone initializes `currBob->name` with a string literal or a `char` stack array? See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28896609/how-to-distinguish-between-strings-in-heap-or-literals) for a similar case.

Comment: And use `getch()` instead of `system("pause")`.

Comment: @CoolGuy: I prefer C over `system(xx)` because it does not needlessly invokes the shell. (There are arguments against `getch` as well -- but I don't have a better recommendation, because I never have to somehow "stop" output as I do not run terminal commands under Windows, where this is an issue.)

Comment: What do you mean with *breaks at the `free` sentence*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The line

```
currBob->name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(n));
```

is wrong because

1. You did not include the space for the NUL-terminator.
2. You [should not cast the result of `malloc`(and family)](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) in C.

Fix the problems by using

```
currBob->name = malloc(strlen(n) + 1);
```

If you are wondering why I've removed `sizeof(char)`, it is because `sizeof(char)` is guarenteed to be 1. So, it is not necessary.

---

As [@EdHeal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/892256/ed-heal) [mentions in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30013648/how-to-free-a-pointer-in-struct#comment48145510_30013667), there is a function called `strdup()` that does `malloc`+`strcpy`. It is POSIX function. If it is available, you can shorten

```
currBob->name = malloc(strlen(n) + 1);
strcpy((*currBob).name, n);
```

to

```
currBob->name = strdup(n);
```

by using this function. Also, note that

```
(*currBob).fix = 0;
(*currBob).max = 3;
```

is equivalent to

```
currBob -> fix = 0;
currBob -> max = 3;
```

as [@Edheal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/892256/ed-heal) [mentions in another comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30013648/how-to-free-a-pointer-in-struct#comment48145484_30013667).

Comment: Also `(*currBob).fix = 0;` could be `currBob->fix = 0;`

Comment: To stay on the save side one could do: `currBob->name = malloc((strlen(n) + 1) * sizeof *(currBob->name));`

Comment: `strdup` might be available

Comment: @EdHeal , Added the `strdup` suggestion and the other one. Thanks for mentioning.