# Bus error when modifying char* string

Tags: c, string, pointers

I got `bus error` from following code:

```
char *my_string = "Hello";
my_string[0] = 'Y';
```

What could be the problem (bug)?

Comment: char my_string[]="Hello"; is ok. it copied into the stack memory. but char *my_string="Hello" is pointing to read only memory. so cannot modify. if you want to use heap memory, use malloc and copy the string to the heap.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that specific question. This is about writing to string literals.

Comment: It's more a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303411/string-literals-vs-const-char-in-c